# PrimarySwatch is not working when useMaterial3 is true

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-design

When I updated Flutter to Flutter 3.7.6, suddenly 'primarySwatch' is not reflected anymore. 'useMaterial3' works if I set it to false, but I don't know why.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
 title: 'Demo',
 theme: ThemeData(
 primarySwatch: Colors.pink,
 appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(elevation: 0),
 useMaterial3: true,
 ),
home: const HomeScreen(),
);
```

I tried setting useMaterial3 to false, but could not think of any other solution.

Comment: This also happen to me, the custom theme/widget is ignored, ex splashRadius on IconButton cant be setted or ignored when useMaterial3 set to true

Answer (score 3):

In Flutter 3, when you enable Material 3 Theming by setting `useMaterial3` to `true`, the `primarySwatch` property is no longer used for color theming.

Instead, you should use `colorSchemeSeed` to specify a seed color. Replace `primarySwatch: Colors.pink` with `colorSchemeSeed: Colors.pink` to reflect your color preference.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorSchemeSeed: Colors.pink,
    appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(elevation: 0),
    useMaterial3: true,
  ),
  home: const HomeScreen(),
);
```